# SMS Retriever API how to get SMS sender/originating Address

Tags: android, sms

Have used the SMS Retriever api to perform SMS-based user verification in my app successfully, however am unable to retrieve the senders address/id. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi. I'm getting problems to run SMS Retriever API in release mode (work in debug mode). Did you something different?? I've started a question about this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865978/why-sms-retriever-api-dont-work-in-release-mode

Comment: @Joshua. Do you got any solution? Even I also need the same.

Comment: @GopinathS Unfortunately, I have not got any solutions

Comment: We are facing the same problem because we have to make sure that this SMS has not been just re-send and comes from our backend.

Comment: I also need this solution.If you find please post it

Comment: I also need to filter sms auto read based on who the sender is. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://garageprojects.tech/using-android-sms-user-consent-api/